# Get current position of scroll with angular 6 ViewportScroller

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a table in my angular 6 code.The no of rows are in hundreds. So i have used infinityScroll(a plug in). So my scrollbar is linked to the table i.e the tbody of the table not the page.
I am using sorting in the ALERT TYPE column, so whenever i will do sorting i want my table will come to position [0,0], i.e the sorting operation will lead the table to come to its initial position(top of the table).

I have used *ViewportScroller* importing from @angular/common. So when i used its method getScrollPosition(), its has given me ithe output of the entire page positin not the table's scroll position. Help me out. I want the scroll position the table shown below.

```
<table class="table table_view_land alertable" matSort
   (matSortChange)="sortData($event);">
   <thead *ngIf="tableShowFlag">
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th mat-sort-header="name">Alert Type      
         </th>
         <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
         <th>status</th>
         <th>last Modified</th>
         <th>attachments</th>
         <th>people</th>
         <th>action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class='main-panel'
   infiniteScroll
   [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
   [infiniteScrollUpDistance]="1.5"
   [infiniteScrollThrottle]="100"
   [infiniteScrollContainer]= "selector"
   [fromRoot]="true"
   (scrolled)="onScrollDown()"
   (scrolledUp)="onScrollUp()"   *ngIf='tableData'>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of sortedData">
      <td>{{data.subject}}</td>
      <td>{{data.description}}</td>
      <td>{{data.caseStatusName}}</td>
      <td>{{data.lastupdate | date : "short" }}</td>
      <td>{{data.activityContentPath.length}}</td>
      <td>{{data.watcherCount}}</td>
      <td>Windows 10 Pro</td>
   </tr>
   <div class="spinLoader" [ng2-loading]="showSpinScroll" [config]="loadingConfig" align="center">
   <!-- <mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="showSpinScroll" class="example-margin" [color]="color" [mode]="mode" [diameter]='diameter'>
      </mat-progress-spinner> -->
   </div>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I have given some try to solve my own issue and stuck her. I think my solution is inside this code below.

```
static ngInjectableDef: defineInjectable({ 
     providedIn: 'root',
     factory: () => new BrowserViewportScroller(inject(DOCUMENT), window) 
 })
abstract setOffset(offset: [number, number] | (() => [number, number])): void
abstract getScrollPosition(): [number, number]
abstract scrollToPosition(position: [number, number]): void
abstract scrollToAnchor(anchor: string): void
abstract setHistoryScrollRestoration(scrollRestoration: 'auto' | 'manual'): void
```

Comment: try using scroll event

Comment: can you please give me some example

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're injecting the ViewportScroller in your constructor.